$n_{k+1} = 2^{n_k} n_k$, find a bound between $n$ and $k$
Let the following sequence:
$n_{k+1} = 2^{n_k} n_k$ with $n_5 = 5$ as starting condition.
I need an asymptotic bound of the type $n_k \le f(k)$ or  $k\ge g(n_k) $ .
Clearly we can write something like $n_6 \le 2^5 5$, $n_7 \le 2^{2^5 5} 2^5 5 $, etc. but it does not narrow what I need. Even a very aggressive bound would help me.
By using a variant of the Lambert function: $x 2^x = z \Longleftrightarrow x = w(z)$ I obtained $w^{k-4}(n_k) \ge 5 $ but I'm not confident this is even true.

The growth rate is already tetrational and comparable with $f_3(n)$ in the fast growing hierarchy. It is difficult to establish a good upper bound.

What do you consider narrow ? I mean, $n_6 = 2^{n_5}n_5 = 2^5 5$, it can't be narrower.

Let's define $a_k = n_{k+5}$ for the sake of simplicity. Now, given that the exponential $2^x$ is an increasing function, as well as $n < 2n \le 2^n \;\forall n \ge 2$, one has :
$$
a_k = 2^{a_{k-1}}a_{k-1} \le 2^{2a_{k-1}} \le 2^{2^{a_{k-1}}} = 2^{2^{2^{a_{k-2}}a_{k-2}}} \le 2^{2^{2^{2^{a_{k-2}}}}} \le \ldots \le 2 \uparrow\uparrow (2k+3) =: f(k),
$$
where the double up-arrow denotes tetration, i.e. $a \uparrow\uparrow b$ being a tower of powers of $a$ with $b$ floors. Note that the "$+3$" term comes from the final majoration $a_0 = 5 < 2^{2^2} = 16$. Conversely, you have
$$
k \ge f^{-1}(a_k) = \log_2^{\circ(2k+3)}(a_k)
$$
You can improve this bound a little bit by taking $g(n) = a_0^{-1}\log_2^{\circ(2k)}(n)$. Finally, if you want to make $g$ independent of $k$, you may define $g(n) = \log_2^{\circ n}(n)$ instead, since $2k+3 < a_k$ for instance.
